# How to run for loop that in every loop there are different result?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    try:
        input1 = int(input("Please type the number: "))
        print("Ok!")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please type it again")
    else:
        break

for i in range(input1):
    print(input1)
```

This is what i want it to be:

```
Please type the number: 4
Ok!
0
1
2
3
```

This is what it gave me:

```
Please type the number: 4
Ok!
4
4
4
4
```

Please give me some advice

Comment: Do not need an else, just put the break after ok ;)

Comment: @azro, he used else to ask user enter again in case if input can't be converted to int, so your advice will break this logic.

Comment: @OlvinRoght nope, because it you have a ValueError you'll go in the except and won't use the break, it tried it's same ;)

Comment: @azro with current code - yes, if you will move break out of else block this loop will end up with single iteration.

Comment: @OlvinRoght with single iteration IF you give valid int, it you give a letter, you'll in the except, then loop again to the question, I've tried so I know what happen :D

Comment: @azro, I have no idea, what have you tried, but [it doesn't work](https://repl.it/repls/ZigzagUnnaturalModem).

Comment: @OlvinRoght of course not here, I said after the OK, just after : https://repl.it/repls/AgedBelatedIrcbot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
for i in range(input1):
    print(input1)
```

It will always print the upper limit of the interval, which is 4.
Try:

```
for i in range(input1):
    print(i)
```

and see how it goes.